# What is the best way to deal with JSON values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, performance

I have a table that I'm searching data on it using 4 columns (idCompanyRadar, idUser, filters and reference). From the beginning I'm using the filter column as a JSON type of MySQL. But later, I was thinking about using index to speed up the queries, and because of that, change the JSON type to maybe a TEXT type to create a index with the 4 columns.

The JSON values stored in that column will be used to compare with the user filter JSON that will be sent on the request (the full JSON, basically verify that the JSON stored is exactly equal to the JSON sent), nothing more, I will not change any value or use the JSON to do anything more than that, so it's kinda part of the index.

Should I transform the column in TEXT type and use index? Or continue to use the JSON type and don't use index? I'm only thinking about query performance.

Comment: Why are people downvoting the question and are not giving any feedback? I'm kinda new  to the use of index and it's a really doubt for me.

Comment: possibly because you're asking for the "best" way, which is a matter of opinion.  Possibly because you don't provide any schema or SQL examples of what you're saying.  comes across as low effort question when you ask about SQL and then don't provide any SQL examples / details in your question just paragraphs of text.  Nothing speaks like the code itself

Comment: But honestly what I need to provide here? All I'm asking is about what type to use in terms of performance: use JSON type and don't use index or use text type along with index, that's all. About schema I thought that the id prefixes indicates integer values itself.

Comment: People sometimes forget that not everyone has 15 years of Stack Overflow to know this "secret rules" and don't even bother to go into the person's profile to see that. But thanks man, in the next questions I will follow this, if I don't lose the right to ask questions here due this.

Comment: Show us a typical JSON string; it may quell the downvoters.  I have provided some of my ["Rules of Thumb"](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots) in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Move the 4 values out of JSON right away.  Put them into suitable datatypes:

- `VARCHAR(...)` is suitable (and indexable) for shorter strings
- `TEXT` is suitable only for very long strings (and not necessarily indexable)
- `DATETIME`, `INT`, etc are better for numeric values.

Then let's see the likely queries so we can better design the indexes, perhaps including some "composite" indexes.

JSON is useful for

- Random stuff that you won't be searching or sorting on.
- Stuff that is absent from most rows.